# How to change HashMap<K, V> value type from Object to String?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, hashmap, type-conversion

What is the easiest/best way to convert

```
Map<String, Object>
```

to

```
HashMap<String, String>
```

The API I am using has methods that return a Map but it would be easier if I didn't have to cast the Object to a String each time.

Also, is this even worth doing? Would a HashMap be faster/more efficient than a Map?

I'm assuming I'll have to loop through the original Map and copy the values to the new HashMap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A Map is a interface so you can't really stay if some other Map impl is faster than Map.
Why would you cast the Object into string? Is the object itself really is a String? Or are doing toString()?

Comment: down casting can be pretty dangerous.  A HashMap is a Map so casting (Map) myHashMap is always fine.  casting (HashMap)myMap is not always true.  this seems like a bad idea

Comment: The Object is a String, but the API leaves it ambiguous so people can store other types of objects too. And if both are maps.. then why would I use a HashMap over the Map object?

Comment: I understand that it seems like a bad idea but for my project it wouldn't be a big deal because I know for a fact that it can be a HashMap. My main question is, why should I use a HashMap instead of a Map? Is it faster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the constructor as others mentioned:

```
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap(oldMap);
```

This will only work however if you know that the `Object`s in question are ***really*** `String`s.

but there is something I should mention:

Do not confuse **interfaces** with **classes**. `Map` is just an **interface**; a *contract* which contains only definitions. A **class** on the other hand is a concrete *implementation* of an **interface**. So it does not make any difference in terms of perfomrance if you use the `Map` **interface** or its runtime type (`HashMap`). It can make a difference however if you swap the implementations  (to `TreeMap` for example).

Edit:

Here is the verbose solution which is liked by EE guys (no casting/rawtypes warning involved):

```
public class MapConverter {
    public Map<String, String> convert(Map<String, Object> oldMap) {
        Map<String, String> ret = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String key : oldMap.keySet()) {
            ret.put(key, oldMap.get(key).toString());
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay well that makes sense. But my main question is, is there a way I can convert `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, String>`? The values I am storing are Strings and I'd rather cast it here than each time I retrieve the value.

Comment: Why don't you use `String`s in the first place? Why `Object`?

Comment: @AdamArold because it's being returned from an external library, not from his own code.

Comment: + 1 for the remark about the difference between interfaces and implementations and for mentioning my solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks! The latter solution is the one I chose. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the copy constructor on raw types works:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap(map);
```

However, the solution is ugly as the type system is ignored.

EDIT1:

When you execute

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        InterruptedException, IOException {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("Bla", new Object());
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap(map);
    System.out.println(hashMap.get("Bla").getClass());
}
```

you get the class cast exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

It is thrown when "System.out.println(hashMap.get("Bla").getClass());" is executed.

Consequently, the casts are actually delayed.

EDIT2:

You can avoid the copy with

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap)map;
```

However, the problem remains the same as the following code shows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        InterruptedException, IOException {
    HashMap<String, Object> oldMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    oldMap.put("Bla", new Object());
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap)oldMap;
    System.out.println(hashMap.get("Bla").getClass());
}
```

It behaves like the other example above in EDIT1.

EDIT3:
What about using a lambda?

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    // 1

    final Stream<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entries = map.entrySet()
            .stream();

    final Function<Map.Entry<String, Object>, String> keyMapper = (
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) -> entry.getKey();

    final Function<Map.Entry<String, Object>, String> valueMapper = (
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry) -> {
        final Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof String) {
            return (String) value;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException("Value '" + value + "' of key '"
                    + entry.getKey() + "' cannot be cast from type "
                    + ((value != null) ? value.getClass().getName() : null)
                    + " to type " + String.class.getName());
        }
    };

    final BinaryOperator<String> duplicateHandler = (key1, key2) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s",
                key1));
    };

    final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = entries.collect(Collectors
            .toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, duplicateHandler, HashMap::new));

    System.out.println(hashMap);
```

If map only has string-to-string entries, it will copy them all.
E.g. Insert

```
    map.put("aKey", "aValue");
```

at comment 1. It will print

```
    {aKey=aValue}
```

which is fine.

If you have at least one string-to-non-string entry in your map, copying will fail.

E.g. Insert

```
    map.put("aKey", 42);
```

at comment 1. It will print

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Value '42' of key ' aKey' cannot be cast from type java.lang.Integer to type java.lang.String
    at ...
```

which shows the string-to-non-string entry.

I know this solution is not so simple but it is safe.

Comment: Of course the output of ``map.toString()`` (which is used implicitly in the ``println`` call) calls the value's ``toString()`` method internally.
This has nothing to do with the return type of a value getter, which OP's question is about.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the types of key and value (like `<String, String>`), you can just cast the whole map:

```
Map<String, String> newMap = (HashMap<String, String>)oldMap;
```

If you need a separate `Map` instance, you can use the constructor of `HashMap` like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> = new HashMap<String, String>((HashMap<String, String>) oldMap);
```

Comment: compiler says "Cannot cast from HashMap<String,Object> to HashMap<String,String>"

Comment: Well I'm stuck with a `Map<String, Object>` and I want to change the value type to String (NOT Object).